# UI5 keeps loading debug sources despite debugging turned off

Tags: sapui5

My SAPUI5 app consumes modules via [SAP CDN](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2d3eb2f322ea4a82983c1c62a33ec4ae). In DevTools Network tab I see that the *initiator* of many files is a debug version (e.g., *jquery-dbg.js*). I checked with SAPUI5 Diagnostics tool, the debugging is disabled.

No `sap-ui-debug=true` flag is provided in URL as well.
I even tried to add the following code to the `<script>` section of the *index.html* but it doesn't help:

```js
window["sap-ui-config"] = {
    "productive" : true
};
```

How can I switch from *jquery-dbg.js* to the production/minified built of jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see that the *initiator* of loading many files is a debug version

There is nothing wrong with that. The reason why `-dbg.js` files are shown is because browsers map the source code with the production code, in order to make reading and debugging easier. Behind the scene, the production code is still run.

To disable source mapping in Chrome for example, go to devtools > Settings > Uncheck "Enable Javascript source maps"

[image: Chrome Source map]

---

- Similar issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1611
- Check [source-maps](/questions/tagged/source-maps) related questions to learn more.